# jQuery change css when mouseenter but only entered content not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple jQuery like this:

```
    $(function () {
        $('.left-menu').mouseenter(function () {
            $('.left-menu-top').css({
                "border-radius": "0px 25px 0px 0px"
            })

        });
        $('.left-menu').mouseleave(function () {

            $('.left-menu-top').css({
                "border-radius": "25px 0px 0px 0px"
            })
        });
    });
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="left-menu-total">
   <div class="left-menu"></div>
   <div class="left-menu-top">
      Title
   </div>
   <div class="left-menu"></div>
   <div class="left-menu"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the style only of the entered `div`, not every `div`. I searched a lot, but can't solve this problem

PS . I added an image of what I want to achieve:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKxln.png)

Comment: Feedback here? Did you resolve with help from the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this`

```
$('.left-menu').mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).css({"border-radius":"0px 25px 0px 0px"})

});
$('.left-menu').mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).css({"border-radius":"25px 0px 0px 0px"})

});
```

`this` will be the mousentered/mousleft DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give a border to the parent of the item entered?

```
$(function(){
    $('.left-menu').on({
        mouseenter:function(){
            $(this).parent().css({borderRadius:'0px 25px 0px 0px'});
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            $(this).parent().css({borderRadius:'25px 0px 0px 0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

You can consolidate your binding into a single `.on()` binding (reducing DOM queries is the best way to increase performance of your jQuery), then affect only the parent of the item entered (use of `this` denotes the specific element entered). I also changed `"border-radius"` to `borderRadius`, the native DOM object, because it is faster than needing to parse the string. You were already using the object-based `.css()` method, so its just a micro-optimization.

Something you should consider, though, is that older browser versions require the prefixes, namely Firefox < 3.6 and Safari < 4. This should accommodate all possible versions:

```
$(function(){
    function setBorderRadius($this,radVal){
        $this.parent().css({
            borderRadius:radVal,
            WebkitBorderRadius:radVal,
            MozBorderRadius:radVal
        });
    }

    $('.left-menu').on({
        mouseenter:function(){
            setBorderRadius($(this),'0px 25px 0px 0px');
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            setBorderRadius($(this),'25px 0px 0px 0px');
        }
    });
});
```

Notice the use of a function. This will cover all bases CSS-wise, but also make the logic much more extendable. Now if you need to affect the `border-radius` of something in the future, you can just input the new item into the function.

And even better way to do this is to create a new CSS class for each one:

```
.MouseEnter {
    border-radius-to:0 25px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 25px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:0 25px 0 0;
}

.MouseLeave {
    border-radius:25px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:25px 0 0 0;
}
```

Then just change classes on mouse enter / leave:

```
$(function(){
    $('.left-menu').on({
        mouseenter:function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('MouseEnter').removeClass('MouseLeave');
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('MouseLeave').removeClass('MouseEnter');
        }
    });
});
```

This appropriately places the CSS burden in the CSS file, the JS burden in the JS file, and reduces the amount of processing that the browser needs to perform.

Not trying to overload you with information, just providing options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the entered div (.left-menu)? or the containing div (.left-menu-top)?

in first case:

```
$(this).css....
```

second case:

```
$(this).closest('.left-menu-top').css(...
```

[jquery .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)